# Which of the following will instantiate a product collection?

Tags: magento-2.0

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getProduct();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection = Mage::getModel({'catalog/product'})->getCollection();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollectionId();
```

Comment: are you taking a certification exam or something?

Answer (score 1):

First of all non of  those can be used at Magento2.

**This code are use for Magento1.**

> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

The above are right and it is only support for Magento1.

For Magento2, you can use

```
<?php
namespace [YourNameSpace];
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```